# Inappropriate Expected declaration error

Tags: ios, swift

Why am I getting an error in this code, it seems perfectly normal to me. I declare 'hills' as a variable but I am still getting the error "Expected declaration" for both 'hills' and 'bg'.

```
var bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "sky")
bg.position = CGPointMake(bg.size.width / 2, bg.size.height / 2)


self.addChild(bg)

var hills = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "hills")
hills.position = CGPointMake(hills.size.width / 2, 300)

self.addChild(hills)
```

Comment: Errors on which lines, show the full error messages

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the reason for the **Expected Declaration** message is that you have placed this code inside of a class without putting it inside of a method.  The example below compiles, but it gives the same error you are seeing if it is not included inside of the `setup` method:

```
class MyNode: SKSpriteNode {
    func setup() {
        var bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "sky")
        bg.position = CGPointMake(bg.size.width / 2, bg.size.height / 2)


        self.addChild(bg)

        var hills = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "hills")
        hills.position = CGPointMake(hills.size.width / 2, 300)

        self.addChild(hills)
    }
}
```